# android Charge intent has no extra data

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to display an alert in a specific Activity when the charging status changes.
this is my receiver class:

```
public class BatteryChargeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String TAG = "receiver";
private ChargeReceiverCallback callback;

public BatteryChargeReceiver(ChargeReceiverCallback callback) {

    this.callback =callback;
    Log.v(TAG,"Inside  Constructor (Callback)");
}

public interface ChargeReceiverCallback {
    public void onReceive(Intent intent);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    callback.onReceive(intent); 

}
```

}

And below is how I instantiate it from my MainActivity's onResume. MainActivity implements my interface and overrides onReceive(intent). I found out that at no stage does  intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1) return anything else then -1.

```
BatteryChargeReceiver batteryReceiver = new BatteryChargeReceiver(this);
    IntentFilter filterPower = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
    registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filterPower);
```

Comment: Use `BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED`: `intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1)`

Comment: You may also want to listen to `"android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"` broadcasts.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention that I simplified my code when asking this. I am doing both things shoe rat suggested without success

Comment: 1. If you are using `EXTRA_PLUGGED` extra (and not `EXTRA_STATUS`), you should update your question content as such. 2. Why do you need the interface? Seems like that's your issue: broadcast receiver and its objects are destroyed as soon as code in `onReceive()` has finished running.

Comment: 1. will fix it
2. I am simply trying to make my activity show a toast when the battery is plugge out.. nothing too fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>`Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` not delivering current plugged-in state - this is probably a change in how API works, but I could not locate any mention of such change in docs.</del>

The broadcast `Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` was never meant to receive current plugged-in type, but it merely lets the receiving end of power connection ([ref.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/06ba55476ee9703c876d223cd41bd73c5f85f42d)). In fact, [`BatteryService.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server/BatteryService.java) broadcasts plain intent without any extra values (lines 410~412 as of this writing):

```
Intent statusIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
statusIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT);
mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(statusIntent, UserHandle.ALL);
```

However, following code with

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

worked on Nexus 5:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "PowerReceiver";

    private final BroadcastReceiver mPowerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Power connected");
                checkPluggedState(context, intent);
            } else if (Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Power disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Unknown action: " + action);
            }
        }
    };

    private void checkPluggedState(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent chargingIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        final int pluggedState = chargingIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        final String msg;
        switch (pluggedState) {
            case 0:
                msg = "The device is running on battery";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC:
                msg = "Plugged into AC charger";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB:
                msg = "Plugged into USB charger";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS:
                msg = "Plugged into wireless charger";
                break;
            default:
                msg = "Unknown state: " + pluggedState;
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(mPowerReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mPowerReceiver);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

According to [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_STATUS), EXTRA_STATUS is for [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)

Comment: If i understand correctly ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED is similar, as can be seen here:
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorChargeState
and here:
tp://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED

Comment: But nowhere does it say that ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED should receive EXTRA_STATUS

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorChargeState 

"Within the associated BroadcastReceiver implementation, you can extract the current charging state and method as described in the previous step." (the previous state being registering the receiver for ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)

Comment: The tutorial documentation tends to have more errors than the individual javadocs. That looks like an error to me. If you look at the code where that broadcast is created (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/BatteryService.java#L409) you'll see that EXTRA_STATUS is never set. it is only set for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/BatteryService.java#L477)